In M365 Admin Center: Active User list how can I set a filter for "does not contain" or for fields that are empty
I am logged into our M365 Admin Center and have the Active Users list up. I am trying to filter the list so that only those who do have the Department column filled are showing, so those who are not currently assigned to a department are hidden. So filtering out the lines with nothing in the Department field.
I am also trying to filter based on the department not containing "Expired".
Such that if I have this list of users:



Display Name
First Name
Last Name
User Principal Name
Department




Ables, Sam
Sam
Ables
sables@MyDomain.com
Maintenance


Adcock, Bobby
Bobby
Adcock
badcock@MyDomain.com
Expired, Electrical


Anderson, Cedric
Cedric
Anderson
canders@MyDomain.com
Dryers


Barn Owl Cameras
Barn
Owl
BarnOwlCameras@MyDomain.com
Expired,


Bigbee, JaLysa
JaLysa
Bigbee
JBIGBEE@MyDomain.com
Health Safety and Environmental


Boydstun, Mike
Mike
Boydstun
mboydstun@MyDomain.com
Log Yard


Burks, Jarah
Jarah
Burks
jburks@MyDomain.com



Clay, Bob
Bob
Clay
bclay@MyDomain.com
Block Prep



And I add my filter to not include those users who don't have a department and/or have a department containing "Expired", then I would expect to see:



Display Name
First Name
Last Name
User Principal Name
Department




Ables, Sam
Sam
Ables
sables@MyDomain.com
Maintenance


Anderson, Cedric
Cedric
Anderson
canders@MyDomain.com
Dryers


Bigbee, JaLysa
JaLysa
Bigbee
JBIGBEE@MyDomain.com
Health Safety and Environmental


Boydstun, Mike
Mike
Boydstun
mboydstun@MyDomain.com
Log Yard


Clay, Bob
Bob
Clay
bclay@MyDomain.com
Block Prep



I'm not sure if both of those filters can be included in one, I'm fine with that being two different filters as long as I can get them to work. If they have to be separated then I would expect the filter for hiding those without a department would return:



Display Name
First Name
Last Name
User Principal Name
Department




Ables, Sam
Sam
Ables
sables@MyDomain.com
Maintenance


Adcock, Bobby
Bobby
Adcock
badcock@MyDomain.com
Expired, Electrical


Anderson, Cedric
Cedric
Anderson
canders@MyDomain.com
Dryers


Barn Owl Cameras
Barn
Owl
BarnOwlCameras@MyDomain.com
Expired,


Bigbee, JaLysa
JaLysa
Bigbee
JBIGBEE@MyDomain.com
Health Safety and Environmental


Boydstun, Mike
Mike
Boydstun
mboydstun@MyDomain.com
Log Yard


Clay, Bob
Bob
Clay
bclay@MyDomain.com
Block Prep



And the filter to hide those whose department includes Expired would look like this:



Display Name
First Name
Last Name
User Principal Name
Department




Ables, Sam
Sam
Ables
sables@MyDomain.com
Maintenance


Anderson, Cedric
Cedric
Anderson
canders@MyDomain.com
Dryers


Bigbee, JaLysa
JaLysa
Bigbee
JBIGBEE@MyDomain.com
Health Safety and Environmental


Boydstun, Mike
Mike
Boydstun
mboydstun@MyDomain.com
Log Yard


Burks, Jarah
Jarah
Burks
jburks@MyDomain.com



Clay, Bob
Bob
Clay
bclay@MyDomain.com
Block Prep



I've tried putting -Expired and I've tried "-Expired", but neither option returned any results for not containing "Expired".
I've tried "" and null for trying to filter out those with nothing in the field, again nothing is returned.
